# Colormap by vector direction in python using quiver

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to colormap vectors by their direction using quiver, in python 2.7.  I read in my data from a text file, get the angle of each vector and normalize so that everything falls between [0,1].  However, when I go to plot the color it comes out that the same color indicates two different directions.

Also, it might be relevant that I'm not plotting the data on a mesh but as points with velocity vectors.  Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as col

import sys

data = np.loadtxt("" + str(sys.argv[1]) + "")
x_dat = data[:,0]
y_dat = data[:,1]
vx_dat = data[:,2]
vy_dat = data[:,3]

rad = np.arctan(vy_dat/vx_dat) * 2
theta = np.degrees(rad)

for i in range(len(theta)):
    if theta[i] < 0:
        theta[i] += 360
    theta[i] /= 360
```

I realize I don't need to convert to degrees. Then I normalize my vectors:

```
N = np.array([])

for i in range(len(vx_dat)):
    N = np.append(N,np.sqrt(vx_dat[i]**2 + vy_dat[i]**2))
    vx_dat[i] = vx_dat[i]/N[i]
    vy_dat[i] = vy_dat[i]/N[i]
```

And finally, I plot it:

```
q = plt.quiver(x_dat, y_dat, vx_dat, vy_dat, theta, units='dots', angles='xy', cmap = 'Blues')
```

Where 'theta' should map the color for each vector based on direction.  However here's what I get out (I zoomed in so it'd be easier to see):

[image]

How can I fix this so that each direction gets a **unique** color?

Comment: The tan function in periodic by Pi; you therefore get exactly two directions within the whole circle which share the same color (those opposite to each other). What you need is the [arctan2 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2), ([`numpy.arctan2`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html) which gives unique angles over the complete circle.

Comment: Thank you so much!  A silly oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested use the `np.arctan2(V,U)` function to calculate your colour value. To return a unique colour use a different colour map, 'Blues' can only return different shades of blue. A cyclic colour map like 'hsv' is more suitable. Try the following:

```
q = plt.quiver(x_dat, y_dat, vx_dat, vy_dat, np.arctan2(vy_dat, vx_dat), units='dots', angles='xy', cmap = 'hsv')
```